# XNA - Cannot See Mouse in Game

Tags: xna, mouse

I've recently started checking out XNA. All is going well and I've even got a working sample started. One thing that's been bugging me is that whenever I place my mouse over the game window it disappears. I don't know if this is the default behavior but I would like to change this so that I can see my mouse. Any and all advice is appreciated.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Simply set `IsMouseVisible` to true in your main game class(preferably in your Initialize method or Game class constructor) :

```
IsMouseVisible = true;
```

Comment: Wow. I can't believe that I didn't think to check for something like that first.

Comment: No problem I searched for a while the first time I needed it too!

Comment: Works for MonoGame 3.6 also.